# How to generate a column in which each entry is a list of elements from other columns?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataset `df` containing 2 columns `mpg` and `cyl`. I would like to generate a third column in which each entry is a list of elements from the other columns. For example, at row 1, given `mpg = 21` and `cyl = 6`. I want the third column to contain `c(21, 6)`. I can do it through a loop

```
data("mtcars")
df <- mtcars[, 1:2]
n <- nrow(df)
df$new <- 0
for (i in 1:n){
  df$new[i] <- list(c(df$mpg[i], df$cyl[i]))
}
```

My real dataset containing a large number of rows, so this loop approach will be not efficient. Could you please elaborate on an efficient way?

Update: I would like the column `new` has a data format like
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an option with `asplit`

```
df$new <- asplit(unname(df[c('mpg', 'cyl')]), 1)
```

`asplit` converts to an 1d vector with names attributes.  If we want to remove those attributes, can be done with converting it with `as.vector` which removes those attributes

```
df$new <- lapply(setNames(asplit(df[c('mpg', 'cyl')], 1), NULL), as.vector)
str(df$new)
#List of 32
# $ : num [1:2] 21 6
# $ : num [1:2] 21 6
# $ : num [1:2] 22.8 4
# $ : num [1:2] 21.4 6
# $ : num [1:2] 18.7 8
# $ : num [1:2] 18.1 6
# $ : num [1:2] 14.3 8
# $ : num [1:2] 24.4 4
# ..
```

If we need to create a `list` of columns

```
df$new <- split(df[c('mpg', 'cyl')], seq_len(nrow(df)))
```

Comment: This is elegant. May I ask how to get back 2 original columns from the column `new`?

Comment: @LEAnhDung your code with `for` loop is also creating a vector instead of columns

Comment: I thought I created a column with `df$new <- 0`, and then fill in the column with loop. I dont understand your comment.

Comment: @LEAnhDung you meant to create the original two columns from `df$new`, in that case, use `do.call(cbind, df$new)`

Comment: When I check the data format of a dataset that I want to compare with (that's why I would like to generate a column `new` like this format), it is https://i.stack.imgur.com/pOQ27.png. Is there anyway to generate the column `new` like this one?

Comment: @LEAnhDung so you want to remove those name attributes

Comment: Sorry for being long on this one. I'm writing a question with a sample of dataset I want to create. Then it would be less ambiguous. I will send you a link when I finish writing it. Thank you so much for your patience.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this could help

```
df$new <- do.call(Map, c(c, df))
```

which gives

```
> df
                     mpg cyl       new
Mazda RX4           21.0   6     21, 6
Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0   6     21, 6
Datsun 710          22.8   4 22.8, 4.0
Hornet 4 Drive      21.4   6 21.4, 6.0
Hornet Sportabout   18.7   8 18.7, 8.0
Valiant             18.1   6 18.1, 6.0
Duster 360          14.3   8 14.3, 8.0
Merc 240D           24.4   4 24.4, 4.0
Merc 230            22.8   4 22.8, 4.0
Merc 280            19.2   6 19.2, 6.0
Merc 280C           17.8   6 17.8, 6.0
Merc 450SE          16.4   8 16.4, 8.0
Merc 450SL          17.3   8 17.3, 8.0
Merc 450SLC         15.2   8 15.2, 8.0
Cadillac Fleetwood  10.4   8 10.4, 8.0
Lincoln Continental 10.4   8 10.4, 8.0
Chrysler Imperial   14.7   8 14.7, 8.0
Fiat 128            32.4   4 32.4, 4.0
Honda Civic         30.4   4 30.4, 4.0
Toyota Corolla      33.9   4 33.9, 4.0
Toyota Corona       21.5   4 21.5, 4.0
Dodge Challenger    15.5   8 15.5, 8.0
AMC Javelin         15.2   8 15.2, 8.0
Camaro Z28          13.3   8 13.3, 8.0
Pontiac Firebird    19.2   8 19.2, 8.0
Fiat X1-9           27.3   4 27.3, 4.0
Porsche 914-2       26.0   4     26, 4
Lotus Europa        30.4   4 30.4, 4.0
Ford Pantera L      15.8   8 15.8, 8.0
Ferrari Dino        19.7   6 19.7, 6.0
Maserati Bora       15.0   8     15, 8
Volvo 142E          21.4   4 21.4, 4.0
```